# "this" keyword in C++ nested classes

Tags: c++, class, nested, this

If I have the following nested classes:

```
class foo {
public:
    class bar {
    public:
        int barMethod() const;
    protected:
        int barVar;
    };

protected:
    int fooVar;
};
```

and then in a .cpp, can I implement `barMethod()` this way?

```
int foo::bar::barMethod() const {
    return this->fooVar + this->barVar;
}
```

What I mean is:
does `this` keyword in a nested class refer to all classes that are upstream in hierarchy?

Answer (score 7):

> does this keyword in a nested class refer to all classes that are upstream in hierarchy?

No, "current" class only. Class nesting is mostly a lexical thing. Unlike in, say, Java, where an inner class can be associated with an instance of an enclosing outer class, `foo::bar` is pretty much like any other class that isn't nested.

If you want to associate an instance of `bar` with an instance of `foo`, you need to capture a reference or a pointer to `foo` in `bar`.

Comment: "is associated" -> "can be associated". This hinges on whether the inner class is declared `static`.

Comment: @Quentin - It shows I haven't done Java in a while, doesn't it? :)

Comment: In C++ every class is - in java terms - static; No concept of inner classes. You may want to implement proxy pattern instead in which case,you' better make the proxy a friend.

Comment: Take std::vector<bool>::reference_type as an example.